# Create a promise/lazily evaluated expression in R

Tags: r, promise, lazy-evaluation, coroutine

I would like to create a promise in R programmatically. I know that the language supports it. But for some reason, there does not seem a way to do this.

To give more detail: I would like to have components of a list lazily evaluated. E.g.

```
x <- list(node=i, children=promise(some_expensive_function(i))
```

I only want to access the second component of the list for very few values of the list. Pre-populating the list with lazy expressions results in very clear, compact and readable code. The background of this algorithm is a tree search. Essentially, I am trying to emulate coroutine behaviour here. Right now I am using closures for this, but the code lacks elegancy.

Is there a third-party package that exposes the hidden promise construction mechanism in R? Or is this mechanism explicitly tied to environment bindings rather than expressions?

P.S. Yes, I am aware of delayedAssign. It does not do what I want. Yes, I can juggle around with intermediate environments, but its also messy.

Comment: I suggest you pose a bit more code using "inexpensive" functions.

Answer (score 1):

Any programming language that has first-class functions (including R) can pretty easily implement lazy evaluation through thunks ([Wikipedia entry on this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation#Implementation)).

The basic idea is that functions are not evaluated until they're called, so just wrap the elements of your list in anonymous functions that return their value when called.

```
delayed <- list(function() 1, function() 2, function () 3)
lapply(delayed, function(x) x())
```

Those are just numbers wrapped in there, but you can easily place `some_expensive_function(i)` in there instead to provide the argument but delay evaluation.

---

Edit: noticed the using closures thing just now, so I assume you're using a similar method currently. Can you elaborate on the "inelegance" of it? This is all eye-of-the-beholder, but thunking seems fairly straightforward and a lot less boilerplate if you're just looking for lazy evaluation.

Comment: That is exactly what I am using right now. I think this is inelegant because one needs to remember that these are functions, and evaluate them explicitly (this is especially problematic for other users that need to use my code). It would be nice if the expression would be implicitly lazily evaluated. Of course, my dislike of this solution is pretty much nit-picking at this point. I am just trying to find the most practical and maintainable solution.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment your use case is too vague to get my head around. I'm wondering if one of `quote`, `expression` or `call` is what you are asking for:

```
x <- list(node=i, children=quote(mean(i))  )
x
#----------
$node
[1] 768

$children
mean(i)
#------------
x <- list(node=i, children=call('mean',i))
x
#-------------
$node
[1] 768

$children
mean(768L)
#-----------
x <- list(node=i, children=expression(mean(i)) )
x
#------------
$node
[1] 768

$children
expression(mean(i))
```

A test of the last one obviously evaluation in the `globalenv()`:

```
eval( x$children)
#[1] 768
```

Comment: The use case if fairly simple. I have one function that generates a search tree, and a bunch of other functions that walk this tree. The search tree can potentially be very large, but only few branches ever need to be walked. By evaluating subtrees lazily, I can improve performance by the factor of 200x or more while keeping the code concise. Another solution to this would be to merge the tree generation and tree walk code, but I do not want to do this for API design reasons. Your proposal is essentially the same as what James offers in the above answer. It still requires explicit evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

I have ended up using environments and delayedAssign for this one.

```
        node <- new.env()
        node$name <- X[1, 1]
        r$level <- names(X)[1]
        delayedAssign('subtaxa', split_taxons_lazy(X[-1]), assign.env=node)

        node
```

This works well for my case, and while I would prefer it use lists, it does not seem to be possible in R. Thanks for the comments!